# c# Substring doesn't find string

Tags: c#, substring

I have this paragraph inside my lotHtmlOriginal.Text

```
waters71 </strong></p>
<p><strong>websitesss.com/sblogin/login.shtml/</strong><br />
<strong>1234213:123123</strong><br />
<strong>213123:12312</strong><br />
<strong>4213:196028</strong><br />
<strong>32131:43423</strong><br />
<strong>4444444:96980507</strong></p>
<p><strong>htt
```

I issue is that when I make the second part of substring `</p>`, the code fails because substring is not able to find it, but when I change it to certain things, it works.

It does not work when I change it too...

- htt
- tron
- p
- `</strong>`

This is my code

```
String St = lotHTMLOriginal.Text; ;
String firstPart = "blogin/login.shtml/</strong>";
String lastPart = "</p>";
int pFrom = St.IndexOf(firstPart) + firstPart.Length;
int pTo = St.IndexOf(lastPart);

String result = St.Substring(pFrom, pTo - pFrom);
lotHTML.Text = result;
```

**And just in case it's not clear, I'm trying to get everything between `blogin/login.shtml/</strong>` and `</p>`**

Comment: frankly, I can't get what do you want to do?

Comment: I'm trying to get everything between `blogin/login.shtml/</strong>` and `</p>`

Comment: Because IndexOf() only  find the first </p>, while what you want is the last </p>?

Comment: @shole does it not find the first </p> after the `firstPart`?

Comment: If you know the patterns you're matching against, why not use a Regular Expression?

Comment: I don't know what you want clearly, but have you tried print pFrom and pTo and see what's their value? maybe you find the <p> in waters71 </strong></p> which is before your first part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to find particular string starting from previously found position like [string.IndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7cct0x33%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
int pTo = St.IndexOf(lastPart, pFrom);
```

Side note: if you need a lot of HTML processing it may be easier to use HTML parser (like HtmlAgilityPack) instead of using string matching or regular expressions, but for simple one-off code substring is ok.

Answer (score 0):

This code will find the first `"</p>"` after the beginning of the firstPart.

```
String lastPart = "</p>";
int pFrom = St.IndexOf(firstPart) + firstPart.Length;
int pTo = 0;
while(pTo - pFrom < 0)
{
    pTo = St.IndexOf(lastPart);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using  `int pTo = St.IndexOf(lastPart);` you will get the index of the first `</p>`, but you are looking for the last one so I think you should use

```
int pTo = St.LastIndexOf(lastPart);
```

**OUTPUT:**

`<br /> <strong>1234213:123123</strong><br /> <strong>213123:12312</strong><br /> <strong>4213:196028</strong><br /> <strong>32131:43423</strong><br /> <strong>4444444:96980507</strong>`

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will fix the bug in your code.  I've added a new variable to the mix.  Let me know if this makes sense / helps.

```
    String St = lotHTMLOriginal.Text; ;
    String firstPart = "blogin/login.shtml/</strong>";
    String lastPart = "</p>";
    int pFrom = St.IndexOf(firstPart) + firstPart.Length;

    // these three lines changed
    string St_temp = St.Substring(pFrom);
    int pTo = St_temp.IndexOf(lastPart);
    String result = St.Substring(pFrom, pTo);

    lotHTML.Text = result;
```

What I ultimately did was to trim the characters before `firstPart` in `St` to simplify the code somewhat.  It limits the arithmetic you need to do to get the result you are looking for.

```
// this is the result
<br />
<strong>1234213:123123</strong><br />
<strong>213123:12312</strong><br />
<strong>4213:196028</strong><br />
<strong>32131:43423</strong><br />
<strong>4444444:96980507</strong>
```